# AFrame - Change controls type using setAttribute

Tags: aframe

I would like to remove the `twoway-motion` component from the entity `player`, and replace it with the `progressive-controls` component, using `setAttribute`.

While the `removeAttribute` works fine for removing the `twoway-motion`, the `setAttribute` does not add the `progressive-controls`.

```
<a-entity id="player" networked="template:#avatar-template;showLocalTemplate:false;" 
            camera spawn-in-circle="radius:3;" 
            position="0 1.3 0" 
            wasd-controls 
            look-controls 
            twoway-motion="speed: 35">

            <a-entity cursor="fuse: true; fuseTimeout: 500"
                position="0 0 -1"
                geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.02; radiusOuter: 0.03"
                material="color: black; shader: flat"
                      id="defaultCursor">
            </a-entity>
  </a-entity>


<script> 
  var playerEl = document.getElementById('player');    
  var cursorEl = document.getElementById('defaultCursor');      

  playerEl.removeChild(cursorEl);

  playerEl.removeAttribute('twoway-motion'); 

  playerEl.setAttribute('progressive-controls');
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `setAttribute(name, value)` requires a value.

To add the component, just use `setAttribute('progressive-controls', '')` to add it with the default schema